# stubbing current_user in view test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In my view I have line with:

```
<%= current_user.username %>
```

In my tests I stub it this way:

```
  view.stub(:current_user) { FactoryGirl.build(:user, username: "Joe") }
```

But in fact I don't need to return whole User object, I just need username. How can I do this?

Something like (I know it's wrong and not working) `view.stub(:current_user.username) { "Joe" }`

Comment: Try this view.stub!(:current_user).and_return current_user.username

Comment: why would you want to just return the username? that does not make any sense to me.

Comment: I want to put it in header like `Hello <%= current_user.username %> | <%= link_to Logout ... `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need `current_user.username`, then you can use:

```
view.stub_chain(:current_user, :username).and_return("Joe)
```